# Aplicação web com React fazendo requests infinitos

Tags: node.js, react

export default class UsuarioBox extends Component{

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {lista: []};
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.Listar();
}

Listar(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user').then(function(resposta){
    this.setState({lista: $(resposta.data)});
  }.bind(this));
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <FormUsuario Listar={this.Listar()} />
            <TabelaUsuario lista={this.state.lista} Listar={this.Listar} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Quando eu subo o servidor o browser começa a travar e quando vou ver no network o mesmo esta fazendo infinitos requests de user na api, acredito eu que o erro esteja em FormUsuario Listar={this.Listar()} /> mas não sei como resolver. Alguma dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforme essa linha

```
<FormUsuario Listar={this.Listar()} />
```

em

```
<FormUsuario Listar={this.Listar} />
```

Executar a função dentro do render provoca uma nova request, que provoca um setState, que provoca um novo render... Loop infinito.
Aliás, o correto é "bindar" o método `Listar` no construtor da classe (ou utilizar arrow functions).

```js
class MinhaClasse extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            lista: []
        };

        this.Listar = this.Listar.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.Listar();
    }

    Listar(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user')
        .then(function(resposta){
            this.setState({lista: resposta.data}
        ).catch((err)=> {});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <FormUsuario Listar={this.Listar} />
                <TabelaUsuario
                    lista={this.state.lista}
                    Listar={this.Listar}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```